# Getting Numeric value not recognized

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

```
 SELECT ID,INDEX,purchase_list,
      NVL(CASE WHEN INDEX = 2 THEN purchase_list END,0)
             AS qty,
sum(NVL(CASE WHEN INDEX = 2 THEN purchase_list END,0))over(partition by ID) as order_qty    
  FROM (
        SELECT ID,index,d.value::string AS purchase_list FROM (
                        SELECT ID,c.value::string AS purchase_list
                          FROM table_1,LATERAL flatten(INPUT=>split(post_purchase_list, '|')) c 
                      ), LATERAL flatten(INPUT=>split(purchase_list, ';')) d
       )WHERE ID=1250707
```

When I run the above query, I'm getting

> Numeric value is not recognized.

The column - post_purchase_list is a VARCHAR column.

Comment: The source column contained empty string so it was not working. It is working fine now. Thanks for your great help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 'this is a string' as this_is_a_str,
    NVL(this_is_a_str, 0) as one_of_these_is_str_and_the_other_is_a_number;
```

also gives:

> Numeric value 'this is a string' is not recognized

Which to say, your types are different, ether cast your "string to a number if it is one" or cast your zero to a string `'0'`

```
SELECT '1234' as this_is_a_str,
    0 as this_is_a_number,
    NVL(this_is_a_str, this_is_a_number::string),
    NVL(this_is_a_str::int, this_is_a_number);
```

this works just fine. Now for you code you are doing this twice.

```
SELECT 
    ID,
    INDEX,
    purchase_list,
    NVL(CASE WHEN INDEX = 2 THEN purchase_list END, '0') AS qty,
    sum(NVL(CASE WHEN INDEX = 2 THEN purchase_list END, '0')) over (partition by ID) as order_qty    
FROM (
    SELECT 
        ID,
        index,
        d.value::string AS purchase_list 
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            ID,
            c.value::string AS purchase_list
        FROM table_1,
            LATERAL flatten(INPUT=>split(post_purchase_list, '|')) c 
    ), LATERAL flatten(INPUT=>split(purchase_list, ';')) d
)
WHERE ID = 1250707
```

but as mentioned before those flattens could be written

```
SELECT 
    ID,
    INDEX,
    purchase_list,
    NVL(CASE WHEN INDEX = 2 THEN purchase_list END,'0') AS qty,
    sum(NVL(CASE WHEN INDEX = 2 THEN purchase_list END,'0')) over (partition by ID) as order_qty    
FROM (
    SELECT 
        ID,
        d.index,
        d.value::string AS purchase_list 
    FROM table_1
        ,LATERAL flatten(INPUT=>split(post_purchase_list, '|')) c 
        ,LATERAL flatten(INPUT=>split(c.value::string, ';')) d
)
WHERE ID = 1250707
```

and the `qty` can be reused:

```
SELECT 
    ID,
    INDEX,
    purchase_list,
    NVL(CASE WHEN INDEX = 2 THEN purchase_list END,'0') AS qty,
    sum(qty) over (partition by ID) as order_qty    
FROM (
    SELECT 
        ID,
        d.index,
        d.value::string AS purchase_list 
    FROM table_1
        ,LATERAL flatten(INPUT=>split(post_purchase_list, '|')) c 
        ,LATERAL flatten(INPUT=>split(c.value::string, ';')) d
)
WHERE ID = 1250707
```

OR

```
SELECT 
    ID,
    d.index,
    d.value::string AS purchase_list, 
    NVL(CASE WHEN d.index = 2 THEN purchase_list END, '0') AS qty,
    sum(qty) over (partition by ID) as order_qty 
FROM table_1
    ,LATERAL flatten(INPUT=>split(post_purchase_list, '|')) c 
    ,LATERAL flatten(INPUT=>split(c.value::string, ';')) d
WHERE ID = 1250707
```

Comment: I tried CAST( <source_expr> AS <target_data_type> ) but it didn't work. I also tried string '0' and it didn't work. I'm doing something wrong. The source datatype in VARCHAR
-